# Is there a way to write into a file while another process is reading?

Tags: c#, c++, file-access

I have a writing process on C++ application, another C# application reads data continuously whenever the file has been changed.

On C++:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(result_file, "a");
if (fp) {
    // Write some thing
    fclose(fp);
}
```

On C#:

```
private void Init() {
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(ResultFolder);
    watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnResultChanged);
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private void OnResultChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
    if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Changed) {
        // Check file ready to read

        // Ready all lines
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(e.FullPath);
        // Process lines
    }
}
```

But sometimes the code on C++ cannot open the file to read, how can I fix it?

P/S: I found that on C# we have a way to share file access such as below command

```
File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
```

But cannot find similar way in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on Windows, so the C++ way is

```
CreateFile(.... FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, ....)
```

It returns a Win32 `HANDLE`, which is not the easiest thing to use in C++ (there are no convenience functions for formatted I/O).  But you can turn it into a `FILE*` or `fstream`.

See this question:

- [Can I use CreateFile, but force the handle into a std::ofstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/475853/103167)

Or, you can use the `shflag` parameter of `_fsopen()` or the `_Prot` parameter of an `fstream` constructor:

> The argument shflag is a constant expression consisting of one of the
>   following manifest constants, defined in Share.h.
>
> Term      Definition
>
> `_SH_COMPAT` Sets Compatibility mode for 16-bit applications.
>
> `_SH_DENYNO` Permits read and write access.
>
> `_SH_DENYRD` Denies read access to the file.
>
> `_SH_DENYRW` Denies read and write access to the file.
>
> `_SH_DENYWR` Denies write access to the file.

MSDN has [the documentation and examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f30b0db.aspx)