# Boost Serialization and Win32 file handle

Tags: c++, winapi, serialization, boost

I have a problem about using Boost.Serialization with Win32 file handle. I want to serialize something to some Win32 file handle created by `::CreateFile` with some special flags (`FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` & `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY`). But I learnt that Boost.Serialization only works with std::ostream.

Any solution?

Comment: This looks like it might work for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475853/can-i-use-createfile-but-force-the-handle-into-a-stdofstream

Comment: @ChristopherOicles Thx!