# error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ifstream' {aka 'std::basic_ifstream<char>'} and 'CHAR [39]' {aka 'char [39]'})|

Tags: c++

i am trying to look if a file name hardware id txt exist, if not then make it and write the hardware id in it, however i keep getting this error that claims that there is no much to an operator.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    HW_PROFILE_INFO hwProfileInfo; // unless we have a very good reason, this should
                                   // not be global
    if(GetCurrentHwProfile(&hwProfileInfo) != NULL)
    { // update info was a success. NOW we have a GUID and can do stuff with
      // hwProfileInfo
        printf("Hardware GUID: %s\n",     hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid);
        printf("Hardware Profile: %s\n", hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileName);
        std::ifstream hwidfile;
        hwidfile.open("hardwareid2.txt");
        if(hwidfile) {
            printf("File exist");
            return 0;
        } else{
            std::ofstream hwidfile { "hardwareid2.txt" };
        }

        if (!(hwidfile << hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid))
        { // will fail if can't write for any reason, like file didn't open
            std::cout << "File write failed\n";
            return -1;
        }


    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "GetCurrentHwProfile failed\n";
        return -1;
    }

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: You can't write into `ifstream` (note the `i` stands for `input`). And you can't have two variables with the same name `hwidfile`.

Comment: ohh alright i understand, how would i go about recieving my desired outcome?

Comment: `std::ofstream` will create file if it's not present, so you can simply open one and if it failed to open, it means program can't create a file for some reason (maybe missing permissions or something). If a file exists, it will be cleared.

Comment: "how would i go about recieving my desired outcome?" **What is** your desired outcome? Where the code says `if (!(hwidfile << hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid))`, **what should happen**?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709395/c-open-file-for-writing-only-if-does-not-exists answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring two separate variables, one `std::ifstream` and one `std::ofstream`, with the same name `hwidfile`. That won't work in your case. You are declaring the `ofstream` in a nested scope that destroyed the `ofstream` before you try to write to it. You can't change a variable's type by re-declaring the same name with a different type.

You are actually calling `operator<<` on the `ifstream`, not the `ofstream`, hence the compiler error. The `ofstream` is out of scope by that time.

If you need a file stream that can be used for both input and output, use a single `std::fstream` variable instead, eg:

```
std::fstream hwidfile;
hwidfile.open("hardwareid2.txt", std::ios_base::in);
if (hwidfile.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "File exists\n";
    return 0;
}
hwidfile.open("hardwareid2.txt", std::ios_base::out);
if (!hwidfile.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "File create failed\n";
    return 0;
}
if (!(hwidfile << hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid))
{
    std::cout << "File write failed\n";
    return -1;
}
```

Otherwise, give each file stream variable different names, eg:

```
std::ifstream hwidfileIn("hardwareid2.txt");
if (hwidfileIn.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "File exists\n";
    return 0;
}
std::ofstream hwidfileOut("hardwareid2.txt");
if (!hwidfileOut.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "File create failed\n";
    return 0;
}
if (!(hwidfileOut << hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid))
{
    std::cout << "File write failed\n";
    return -1;
}
```

Or, simply get rid of the `ifstream` and use `std::filesystem::exists()`  or equivalent instead, eg:

```
if (std::filesystem::exists("hardwareid2.txt")) {
    std::cout << "File exists\n";
    return 0;
}
std::ofstream hwidfile("hardwareid2.txt");
if (!hwidfileOut.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "File create failed\n";
    return 0;
}
if (!(hwidfile << hwProfileInfo.szHwProfileGuid))
{
    std::cout << "File write failed\n";
    return -1;
}
```