# How can i get ostream object from the descriptor of a standard output device?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have the descriptor of a standard output device (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE).
Can I use it to create an object ostream ?

This descriptor for the console

```
HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
```

Comment: Not sure if POSIX is correct. But there is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475853/can-i-use-createfile-but-force-the-handle-into-a-stdofstream

Comment: @PhilM And what if it's not a file, but a console?

Comment: I don't know; they are both HANDLEs, so there's at least a small chance it might work. I'm curious to know, so if either of the two links works (or doesn't), comment back.

Comment: Despite the fact that it is a duplicate anyway, please take two second to think about using the correct tags fpr your questions. There is no such thing as an ostream in C.

Comment: Note that a handle is not the same thing as a descriptor.  You can convert a handle to a descriptor using _open_osfhandle.