# Can two different processes communicate with each other using Windows events in WINAPI?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, custom-events

I am in the midst of developing two applications that communicate using a file. These applications are running on the same machine. To be clear, I have a `writer.exe` and a `reader.exe` executables.

The `writer.exe` constantly writes a random integer to a common file `"some_file.bin"` and closes the file. It repeats the same process again: opens the file, writes random `int` and closes it. This is done in a while loop.

The `reader.exe` is constantly reading the file `"some_file.bin"`, printing the read integer to its console.

Both of these applications are written in C++ using the `std::fstream` class for file I/O.

So far, this is not working properly, because we have a race condition happening here.

I want some way to properly communicate between these two processes, using Win32 Events, so that the `writer.exe` process knows to wait until the `reader.exe` process has finished reading, and the `reader.exe` process knows to pause until the `writer.exe` process has finished writing.

I'm hoping to do this using the `CreateEvent`, `WaitForSingleObject` family of API calls present natively on the Windows platform.

Please feel free to tell me if this is possible **between** two processes?

So far, I have only found examples using the above APIs to signal threads of one main process... ?

Comment: windows events are global and can be used between processes

Comment: Sounds like a [pipe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/pipes) is what you need. One process writes to it, the other reads from it, nothing gets lost, nothing gets read more than once.

Comment: [Interprocess Communications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications).

Comment: IIRC Visual Studio's `std::ifstream` will happily _read_ from a pipe, but creation requires non-portable functions. You can then still write to that pipe using [`ofstream`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475853/can-i-use-createfile-but-force-the-handle-into-a-stdofstream)

Comment: @Gal "*windows events are global and can be used between processes*" - more accurately, an Event *can* be used globally between processes, but *is not* global unless you *explicitly* ask for that behavior, by assigning a sharable name to it which both processes can then open a handle to.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes I will give a common name as the last argument to ```CreateEventA()``` :)

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I loved the idea of a pipe. But the first process will indefinitely continue to edit the common file. The other process reads the file continuously. If I'm using a pipe, how can a synchronization happen? I have experience using pipes in Linux but I'm new to Windows pipes ... Can you please tell me, some sources where I can learn more about Win32 pipes... :)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/synchronous-and-overlapped-input-and-output

Comment: You also might consider https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html. NOTE: I have used this on windows before, but note, the behavior of the shared memory, which is not closed properly (like a crash would do) is differemt between platforms (or was when I tried)

Comment: You can use Win32 private messages. The other method is with TCP/IP (especially if you need to transfer more data between apps).

Comment: @VivekanandV "*If I'm using a pipe, how can a synchronization happen?*" - you wouldn't need to sync them. The writer would create the pipe, wait for a reader to connect, and then continuously write ints to it. The reader would connect to the pipe and then continuously read ints from it." *please tell me, some source where I can learn more about Win32 pipes*" - the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/pipes) is a good place to start.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Events are always sharable. You can Duplicate/Inherit without ever using a name.

Comment: @Anders well, you *can*, but that also requires explicit action to setup. So, they are not inheritable/duplicated *by default* if you just create them as-is without asking for that extra setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is *possible*. When one process creates a handle to an Event object, you have the option of assigning a name to that object in the kernel. The other process can then create/open its own handle to that Event object using the same name.

Note that to accomplish what you want, you actually would need 2 Events, eg:

writer.exe:

```cpp
HANDLE hReadable = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, TEXT("ReaderCanRead"));
if (!hReadable) ...

HANDLE hWritable = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, TRUE, TEXT("WriterCanWrite"));
if (!hWritable) ...

...

while (!quit)
{
    ...
    WaitForSingleObject(hWritable, INFINITE);
    if (quit) break;
    // write int...
    SetEvent(hReadable);
    ...
}
```

reader.exe:

```cpp
HANDLE hReadable = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, TEXT("ReaderCanRead"));
// or: HANDLE hReadable = OpenEvent(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, TEXT("ReaderCanRead"));
if (!hReadable) ...

HANDLE hWritable = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, TRUE, TEXT("WriterCanWrite"));
// or: HANDLE hWritable = OpenEvent(EVENT_MODIFY_STATE, FALSE, TEXT("WriterCanWrite"));
if (!hWritable) ...

...

while (!quit)
{
    ...
    WaitForSingleObject(hReadable, INFINITE);
    if (quit) break;
    // read int...
    SetEvent(hWritable);
    ...
}
```

That being said, you might consider using a named block of shared memory via `CreateFileMapping()`+`MapViewOfFile()`, rather than using a physical file.

However, there are many other Inter-Process Communication mechanisms that are way more suitable to your producer/consumer model than using a shared file/memory protected by Events. Pipes, sockets, mailslots, even window messages, would be a much better choice.

Comment: Thankyou very much! :) Can the reader process use OpenEvent() because the writer process starts first, and the names might already be registered in the kernel? Is that possible?

Comment: @VivekanandV yes, of course. I've updated my example to show this. But using `CreateEvent()` in both processes would accomplish the same thing. `OpenEvent()` fails if the event doesn't exist yet. `CreateEvent()` creates the event if it doesn't exist yet. Nothing wrong with having the reader create the events if it starts first, it just won't have any data to read until the writer starts. But, use whichever method best suits your needs.

Comment: Should I use ```ResetEvent(..) ``` ?

Comment: @VivekanandV my example is using auto-reset events, so no. If you use manual-reset events, then yes, call `ResetEvent(event)` after `WaitForSingleObject(event)`

Comment: Thankyou very much! :) I highly appreciate your knowledge :) I love both Windows as well as Linux API. I'm trying to learn a lot of WINAPI myself, these days! :)